# Username and email check for REST API

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

I am new to `php` development. I have created a `REST API` in which `employees` are created and the list of employees is generated. The tool for checking the API is `postman`.

Now I want to do is that when username and email are entered, it will check for both of them that if the username and email are already taken then it will not create rather than it will give an error message.

As a newbie in php, i am unable to find the perfect example. Below is the code

**Employee Model**

```
class Employee extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'employee';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['emp_name', 'emp_email', 'emp_sal'], 'required'],
        [['emp_name', 'emp_email', 'emp_sal'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
    ];
}


public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['create'] = ['emp_name','emp_email', 'emp_sal'];
    return $scenarios;

}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'emp_name' => 'Emp Name',
        'emp_email' => 'Emp Email',
        'emp_sal' => 'Emp Sal',
    ];
}
```

**Employee Controller**

```
 public function actionCreateEmployee()
{


   \Yii::$app->response->format= \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;


    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee-> scenario = Employee::SCENARIO_CREATE;

    $employee->attributes = \Yii::$app->request->post();

    if ($employee->validate())
    {
        $employee->save();
        return array('status'=> true, 'data' => 'Employee Created Sussessfully');
    }
    else
    {
        return array('status'=> false, 'data'=>$employee->getErrors());
    }
    //return array('status'=> true);
}

public function actionListEmployee()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format= \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $employee = Employee::find()->all();

    if(count($employee)>0)
    {
        return array('status' => true,'data'=> $employee);
    }
    else{
        return array('status'=>false, 'data'=> 'No Employee Record Found');
    }

}
```

The `ID` is auto incremented.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does your `employee` table have unique index for name and email? if not then add unique index and try to generate employee model with gii or directly add unique validation for name and email in model itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii2 has validation for uniqueness. To implement this, you have to add this in the rules array for the fields that you want to check for uniqueness. In your case, this will be as follows:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['emp_name', 'emp_email', 'emp_sal'], 'required'],
        [['emp_name', 'emp_email', 'emp_sal'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['emp_email'],'unique','message'=>'Employee email has already been taken. Use another email.'],
        [['emp_name'],'unique','message'=>'User name has already been taken.']
    ];
}
```

You can check this link if you want to know more about the unique validator of Yii2 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html